# App not launching titanium android

Tags: android, titanium

I've tried about everything by now, including googling for 45 minutes. I really don't know what to make from it anymore.

My app won't launch when i start my Android emulator. I'm pretty sure there is no mistake in my code, since it's just a new default project without any edits whatsoever.

Could anyone please look at my log and see what's going on?

Thanks in advance

log:
http://pastie.org/private/imf4bi1cn5brcttn0gjta

edit: I'm on windows 7 64-bit. Not sure if it's helpful...

P.s. My Debug says the application installer was terminated:

```
[INFO] logfile = C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\xxxx\titanium\xxxx\build.log
[INFO] Building timen for Android ... one moment
[ERROR] JDK version 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. detected, but at least 1.6.0 is required
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
```

Comment: Is this just a basic project with no extra code in it?  For example, did you create a new single window application and just try to run it?  See if that works first.

Comment: It's a default project and i ran it. I changed my Java and Android SDK path variables aswell. To no avail...

Comment: Looks like you need to update the version of Java from the error message.

Comment: I installed Java this morning. :-)

Comment: add it to global path so it can execute Java

Comment: I've added the path variable (JAVA_HOME). That's not what you mean i suppose?

Comment: If you go to Start->Run and type "javac -version" without the quotes, does that command execute anything?  Does the version show as 1.6.0 or higher?

Comment: C:\Users\xxx>javac 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Check my screenshot: http://www.envyum.nl/jdk.png

Comment: Did you install the runtime or the SDK?  You'll need the SDK.  Since you are missing all the paths and javac, looks like you installed the wrong version of java.

Comment: I've got the JDK. I've added it to my path as such: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\

Comment: I don't have a JAVA_HOME declaration in my user variables like your java entry.  It is actually in my path section and defined as C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin.  Yours will still have the (x86) in the path.  The bin folder is the one containing my javac program.  I can also run javac -version in my command prompt.  Might need to log off and back on again to refresh the paths.

Comment: My java is running properly now but still no success with launching the app when starting the emulator. If i launch it as a webapp it does work, so the app is correct (Couldn't go wrong on a new default project though)

Comment: Woops, Java fixed it. I just didn't wait long enough to get the app launched in my emulator. Thanks for the info